# Random SQL connection issues. Works, then doesn't work, then works, then BAM! Never works again?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

I am using WebMatrix here, and have a DB, and it was all working just fine until it randomly threw an error at me about a connection string not being there. And this always happens from time to time, and I'm assuming it's a bug in WebMatrix where it just forgets or loses a setting somewhere, because it's not related to any change that I've made.

Here's the error, along with the stacktrace: (apologies for such a long error)

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Source Error: 


Line 1:  @{
Line 2:     WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("SV", "UserProfile", "UserId", "Email", true);
Line 3:      WebMail.SmtpServer = "mail.sv.com";
Line 4:      WebMail.EnableSsl = false;


Source File: d:\HostingSpaces\svisible\sv.com\wwwroot\_AppStart.cshtml    Line: 2 

Stack Trace: 


[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5064474
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity) +341
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) +129
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) +270
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +195
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +232
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +185
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +33
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +524
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +479
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +108
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +125
   WebMatrix.Data.Database.EnsureConnectionOpen() +44
   WebMatrix.Data.<QueryInternal>d__0.MoveNext() +71
   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +4232308
   WebMatrix.Data.Database.QuerySingle(String commandText, Object[] args) +103
   WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CheckTableExists(Database db, String tableName) +59
   WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateTablesIfNeeded() +55
   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeMembershipProvider(SimpleMembershipProvider sMembership, DatabaseConnectionInfo connect, String userTableName, String userIdColumn, String userNameColumn, Boolean createTables) +73
   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeProviders(DatabaseConnectionInfo connect, String userTableName, String userIdColumn, String userNameColumn, Boolean autoCreateTables) +51
   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(String connectionStringName, String userTableName, String userIdColumn, String userNameColumn, Boolean autoCreateTables) +51
   ASP._Page__AppStart_cshtml.Execute() in d:\HostingSpaces\svisible\sv.com\wwwroot\_AppStart.cshtml:2
   System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage.<ExecuteInternal>b__3() +65
   System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage.<GetSafeExecuteStartPageThunk>b__a(Action action) +7
   System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage.ExecuteInternal() +78
   System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage.ExecuteStartPageInternal(HttpApplication application, Action`1 monitorFile, Func`2 fileExists, Func`2 createInstance, IEnumerable`1 supportedExtensions) +202
   System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage.ExecuteStartPage(HttpApplication application, Action`1 monitorFile, Func`2 fileExists, Func`2 createInstance, IEnumerable`1 supportedExtensions) +41

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' was thrown.]
   System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage.ExecuteStartPage(HttpApplication application, Action`1 monitorFile, Func`2 fileExists, Func`2 createInstance, IEnumerable`1 supportedExtensions) +88
   System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage.ExecuteStartPage(HttpApplication application) +287
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule.StartApplication(HttpApplication application, Action`1 executeStartPage, EventHandler applicationStart) +113
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule.StartApplication(HttpApplication application) +71
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication application) +217
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +517
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +194
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +339
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +253

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' was thrown.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9079228
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +256




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.237
```

Why does WebMatrix keep doing this to me? Can someone please try to help me resolve this? I have searched endlessly, and have found plenty of somewhat-related pages but not able to get it working.

Thank You

Comment: do you monitor the SQL SErver itself for errors ? maybe the problem is not ins the application layer, but in the database layer

Comment: It's not webmatrix you just have a flakey connection to the database server. THe error is not saying the connection string is not there it is saying it can't connect to the database.

Comment: Hmm has SO changed? I'm trying to +1 your comments but there's no option.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what to look for - everything was working, and I can access the database from Navicat, and execute queries/inserts against it from another website, also made in webmatrix.

Comment: Error saying that you have some kind of network issue, can you ensure that network connection between an application and database is stable?

Comment: @BENDR - +1'ing a comment is a [privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges) which I believe you require 15 points for.

Comment: Might be a bad server not sure had, what sounds like, the same problem at work(bad server, impossible to stay connected, and just was slow to use). How about increasing the connection timeout that might reduce the number of times you get the error but wont eliminate it from happening.

Comment: Thank you, @Trio - this worked for me. It hasn't stopped it, but it has stopped happeningiiiiii as often now. I'll contact my host and see what's going on because I can't have this happening on launch day lol

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I have followed [this post](http://mvcdiary.com/2012/09/28/my-problem-with-simplemembership-mvc4-and-authorizeattribute-and-roles/) but without any luck.

I wish someone had a solution. This happens randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Check and make sure that TCP Chimney is disabled on both your web server and the SQL Server.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg162682(WS.10).aspx

Comment: random downvote on an item from nearly two years ago with no explanation?